# I want to add a certain onclick function with certain hrefs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

All links whose href's begin with https://www.e-junkie.com/ecom/gb.php?c=cart&ejc=2

add the following attribute:

onclick="return EJEJC_lc(this);

I've only got this far but i don't know how to add the `onlick` function to it

```
$("a[href$='https://www.e-junkie.com/ecom/gb.php?c=cart&ejc=2'].")
```

Comment: That's great! What have you tried so far?

Comment: See jQuery's [Attribute Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Comment: `$("a[href$='https://www.e-junkie.com/ecom/gb.php?c=cart&ejc=2'].")`
 ive only got that far but i dont know how to add the onlick function to it

Comment: See jQuery's [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) or [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: `$("a[href$='https://www.e-junkie.com/ecom/gb.php?c=cart&ejc=2'].").click(function()
{
   onclick = "return EJEJC_lc(this)";
});`   So it would be something like this?

Comment: @DavidVerduzco no. See my answer below for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just needed to add the `on()` method.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$('a[href^="https://www.e-junkie.com/ecom/gb.php?c=cart&ejc=2"]').on("click", function(){ 
  EJEJC_lc(this);
});
```

Comment: only issue is that is an exact match, not begins with

Comment: `=` should be `^=`

Comment: Yeah I missed that part in his question. Thanks